# PHP filter_var FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN expects parameter 2 to be long

Tags: php, string, error-handling, warnings, sanitization

This simple code:

```
var_dump(filter_var('example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN)); 
// also
var_dump(filter_var('example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN, FILTER_FLAG_HOSTNAME));
```

Returns:

```
Warning: filter_var() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in [...]
```

But `FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN` seems to be a valid filter based on [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

And that is how I understand it should be used based on [filter var function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).

What is wrong ?

Comment: Do you define `FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN` anywhere, I can't reproduce your problem as the code stands.

Comment: Your code looks ok. It works at https://phpize.online/?phpses=580f771903c664799c1f9e12448d7356&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80 Please check what contains yor constants `var_dump(FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN, FILTER_FLAG_HOSTNAME);`

Comment: FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN requires PHP 7, are you sure you are on at least 7?

Comment: I was using `PHP 5.x`, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears [`FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN` only exists in PHP 7+](https://3v4l.org/Ivv7G). It's only mentioned in [the general changelog](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.0.0), not where you'd [expect it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php). In older versions it's not defined, and PHP falls back to `'FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN'` as a bare string, and you have suppressed your error reporting and aren't seeing that notice.

Comment: Specifically: *Notice: Use of undefined constant FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN - assumed 'FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN'*